# how to use qutip in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, qutip

I am a beginner of QuTip (a library of python?) user. I have already installed my qutip in my environment by conda. I can execute simple program in jupyter book but not in VScode. How can I do it in VScode?

What I tried:

`import qutip`

`qutip.about()`

However the result shows:

`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'qutip' has no attribute 'about' (most likely due to a circular import)`

I tried executing it by Jupyter book and Anaconda prompt and they work. So why or how can I use it in Visual Studio code?

Note: I open Anaconda prompt, go into my python environment which I install qutip and execute above script.

Note2: I followed the installation steps here: https://qutip.org/docs/latest/installation.html#installing-with-conda

Note3: In visual studio code, I use command line to call my python environment which I installed qutip (I have set Path variable when I installed Anaconda) and execute above scripts.